# Creating a new string of characters by copying them from an existing string and returning the new string in a "results" array?

Tags: c

im asking the user to enter a string say "Investments". Then it asks the user to enter two space separated integers for "start" and "count". What the code does is it sends those inputs to a function called GetSubstring and GetSubstring takes the source string "Investments", and starts at the string designated by the "start" input, and then counts up to the amount of characters in the "count" input and takes what was iterated and saves that in the result array and sends it back to the main function to be printed out. So if i enter "Investments" for the string, 2 for "start", and 4 for "Count". It would return "vest" in the results array.

My problem is in GetSubstring function in the second while loop, maybe a while loop is the wrong approach or im using the pointers in the wrong way, but the first loop cuts out the unwanted original characters and then im trying to start at that new "source" in the second loop and then count and pull out the string based off the number set in "count". I then append a null operator at the end of that new string and send it back via return.

I am new to C, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Below is the code:

```
Main Function:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STR_SIZE 256

//Function Declarations
char *GetSubstring(const char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);

int main(void)
{
    //Create source and result string arrays
    char source[STR_SIZE];
    char result[STR_SIZE];

    printf("Please enter any space separated string: ");

    //Pull in string and replace the newline character with the null zero
    fgets(source, STR_SIZE, stdin);
    source[strcspn(source, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("\nPlease enter a space separated start index,"
           "and character count: ");

    int start;
    int count;
    //Pull in start index and character count
    scanf("%d %d", &start, &count);

    //Return extracted string from source string
    char ReturnArray = *GetSubstring(source, start, count, result);

    //Print results
    printf("\"%s\", %d, %d, extracts \"%s\"",
           source, start, count, ReturnArray);

    return 0;
}
```

GetSubstring FUNCTION:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Function Declarations
char *GetSubstring(const char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    char ResultCopy = result;

    while (source != '\0' && start != 0)
    {
        source++;
        start--;
    }

    while (source != '\0' && count != 0)
    {
        *(result++) = *(source++);
        count--;
    }
    ResultCopy = *result += "\0"; //Add null terminator to end of new string

    return (ResultCopy);
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should be telling you that `char ResultCopy = result;` and `return (ResultCopy);` are using the wrong types. If not, turn compiler warning level up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultCopy` needs to be declared `char *`, not `char`, to match `result` and the return type of the function.

You shouldn't reassign `ResultCopy` at the end. The whole point of that variable is to remember the original value of `result`, since you increment that during the copying loop.

You need to assign the character `'\0'`, not a string `"\0"` to store a null terminator in the result. And just use `=` rather than `+=`.

```
char *GetSubstring(const char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    char *ResultCopy = result;

    while (source != '\0' && start != 0)
    {
        source++;
        start--;
    }

    while (source != '\0' && count != 0)
    {
        *(result++) = *(source++);
        count--;
    }
    *result = '\0'; //Add null terminator to end of new string

    return ResultCopy;
}
```

And in `main()`, you need to declare the result like this:

```
char *ReturnArray = GetSubstring(source, start, count, result);
```

In your code `ReturnArray` is just a single `char`, not a string, and it just contained the first character of the result. Then you got undefined behavior when you used a `char` argument with `%s` format, which requires a pointer to a string.

Comment: In fact, reassigning `ResultCopy` at that place in `GetSubstring()` is not just unnecessary, but should get you a warning at compile time and a segmentation fault at runtime.  Be aware that `GetSubstring` is modifying the contents of the character array `result` in-place. The use of `+=` and the mistaken belief that you need to declare a separate `ReturnArray` to receive the result suggests that there may be some confusion about this (you can go forward using the existing variable `result` instead).

Comment: The purpose of `ResultCopy` is to save the pointer to the beginning of the array, since it increments that pointer during the loop.

Comment: Understood,  but the OP's `ResultCopy = *result = 0` is the part i'm referring to: not just unnecessary, actually fatal.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant by "No need to reassign it".

Comment: I realize I was commenting on your answer but using "you" to refer to the OP. Apologies for confusion

Comment: @jez I have a feeling that some of what he was doing on that line was just to silence some compiler warnings that he didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, i really appreciate the help i cant believe it was something so simple and ive wracked my head over it for quite some time now. One last question, in the main function, the word "vest" in this case thats saved in the result array. I am having a hard time printing it off? Nothing prints, and then the program just ends. It looks like it loops a few times, do i have to specifically ask for that specific array, i.e. ReturnArray[4], in printf?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the problem in `main()`

Comment: @TIN_MAN_025  Use   `GetSubstring(source, start, count, result);  printf("%s\n", result);`  Don't try to dereference the results of `GetSubstring` with `*` or `[]`.   `printf`'s `%s` token expects you to pass a pointer to the start of a string.  The variables that denote strings are best thought of as pointers rather than arrays, when you pass them around (even if the function into which you're passing them has a prototype that says `char []`, it will be acting on a memory address, not a copy of the sequence).

Comment: @Barmar, ahh, and now we are pointing to the address where the full string is in correct? Thanks again for all the help. I appreciate the insight and learning opportunity.